# Do you need In-App Purchase Capability/Entitlement in production to let users buy songs on iTunes with an SKStoreProductViewController?

Tags: ios8, in-app-purchase, xcode6, storekit, itunes-store

My latest app update got rejected by Apple because their testers indicated that they can't buy songs with my app. In particular, it looks like the SKStoreProductViewController loadProductWithParameters never calls its completionBlock in my code. Everything works fine for me in development.

I realize it could be many things going wrong but would like to clearly eliminate this possibility: do I need In-App Purchase Capability/Entitlement to use an SKStoreProductViewController in prod?

Answer (score 0):

I asked Apple directly and the answer is no. You don't need the In-App Purchase Capability/Entitlement to use an SKStoreProductViewController to let your users buy music on iTunes.